# Deploying laravel to NAS

Tags: php, apache, laravel, synology

I've been wrapping my head arround this for the last 2 weeks.

I'm trying to deploy my laravel 4.2 app to my server but cant be able to get past the home page. It was all working fine on my localhost.

When i'm clicking on a link i get a 404 error.

I've already set my httpd.conf file to: AllowOverwride All
Also i placed my htacces file in the public folder.

**My routes.php:**

```
     Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});


//Contact Page
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@getContact');
Route::resource('producten','ProductsController');
//Form request:: POST action will trigger to controller
Route::post('contact_request','ContactController@getContactUsForm');
Route::get('info', function()
{
    return View::make('info');
});

Route::get('diensten', function()
{
    return View::make('diensten');
});

Route::get('tarieven', function()
{
    return View::make('tarieven');
});
```

**Piece of the paths.php file:**

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The public path contains the assets for your web application, such as
    | your JavaScript and CSS files, and also contains the primary entry
    | point for web requests into these applications from the outside.
    |
    */

    'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Base Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The base path is the root of the Laravel installation. Most likely you
    | will not need to change this value. But, if for some wild reason it
    | is necessary you will do so here, just proceed with some caution.
    |
```

**htacces file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**piece of Httpd.conf file:**

```
User http
Group http

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

ServerAdmin admin
ServerName *

<VirtualHost _default_:80 _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/services/web/pcvoorne.nl/public"
Include conf/extra/mod_fastcgi.conf
</VirtualHost>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/services/web">
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.cgi index.php index.php5
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog /run/apache22-error_log
#ErrorLog /dev/null
TraceEnable off
```

What am i missing to make this work?
Hope you can help me out:)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry have to confirm this: is mod_rewrite installed? Would be great to see more details on the 404 error. Do you see index on '/'?

Comment: Please use @stackoverflow properly. You should ask questions only in comments (to ask for more informations) and not in answers. The answer feature should only be used to **answer** the question poster's question, and not being used to ask for more infos.